# I want to use useEffect once i submit a form and take the value from input field and assign it to a api url and get response

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-effect

I am trying to make a ip tracker with an API.I am using form input and useState to get a value from the user and assign it to the API ip value.I am using a custom useFetch hook to fetch the data using the value from state.I want the useFetch to run only when form is submitted or submit button is clicked.But it renders null initially and renders every time i put a input.
I am new to react and learning from scratch.please point out my mistakes.

**Here is my useFetch hook:**

```
      import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    export const useFetch = (url, options, dep) => {
        const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                setIsLoading(true);
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(url, options);
                    const json = await res.json();
                    setResponse(json);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                } catch (error) {
                    setError(error);
                }
            };
            fetchData();
        }, [dep]);
        return { response, error, isLoading };
    };
```

**Header file:**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FaArrowRight } from 'react-icons/fa';
import React from 'react';
import { Form, FormInput, Head, HeadLine, Button } from './Header.elements';
import { useFetch } from '../../useFetch';

const Header = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [Ip, setIp] = useState(value);
    const API_KEY = 'at_xtpIidIz9vUqEzBODaUwtVRXf';
    const URL = `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${API_KEY}&ipAddress=${Ip}`;

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIp(value);
    };
    const { isLoading, response, dep } = useFetch(URL, '', setIp);

    console.log(response);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <>
   
              {/* styled components */}

            <Head>
                   
                <HeadLine>IP Address Tracker</HeadLine>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <FormInput
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={value}
                        placeholder='Search for any IP address or Domain'
                    />
                    <Button type='submit'>
                        <FaArrowRight />
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </Head>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

**App.js file:**

```
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import GlobalStyle from './globalStyles';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Header />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

React hooks are supposed to run each time the component renders, it's described a bit in the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). What you are likely seeing is the returned value each render. I'm sure if you checked your network tab in the browser you'd see only 1 request made from the `useEffect`'s callback function where the `fetch` is made.

I think you've mixed up the `useFetch` dependency since `setIp` is the state updater function and is a stable reference, so it will never trigger the `useEffect` hook to rerun the callback. I think you want the `Ip` state value to be the dependency, i.e. `useFetch(URL, '', Ip);`.

```
const { isLoading, response, error } = useFetch(URL, '', Ip);
```

The hook: You may also want to clear the loading state in a `finally` block so regardless of success or failure you can update your UI accordingly when you are no longer actively fetching data. I suggest also passing in multiple dependencies in case you've more of them. The change here is to just pass an entire dependency array.

```
export const useFetch = (url, options, deps) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, deps); // <-- pass dependencies
  return { response, error, isLoading };
};
```

Usage: defined the dependency array here

```
const { isLoading, response, error } = useFetch(URL, '', [Ip]);
```